# How to emit from one component to another? The parent child thing confuses me

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make a calculator to practice Vuejs and when I click the button I can see an emit being broadcasted in the browsers vue tab in dev tools but the listener isn't catching anything.

Here is the ButtionIO.vue

```
<template>
    <button @click="$emit('trigger-emit', value)" class="btn btn-secondary m-2" type="button">{{ value }}</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ButtonIO',
    props: ['value'],  
}

</script>
```

Here is the DisplayInput.vue component where I want to listen for the emit

```
<template>
<input type="text" class="form-control" @trigger-emit='handleEmit'>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name: 'DisplayInput',
    data: function() {
        return {

        };
    },
    methods: {
        handleEmit()
        {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

and in the App.vue I just have it like this

```
<template>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <DisplayInput />
        </div>
        
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <ButtonIO value="1"/>
            <ButtonIO value="2" />
            <ButtonIO value="3" />
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <ButtonIO value="4" />
            <ButtonIO value="5" />
            <ButtonIO value="6" />
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <ButtonIO value="7" />
            <ButtonIO value="8" />
            <ButtonIO value="9" />
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <ButtonIO value="+" />
          <ButtonIO value="-"/>
          <ButtonIO value="*" />
          <ButtonIO value="/" />
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <ButtonIO value="=" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import ButtonIO from './components/ButtonIO.vue';
  import DisplayInput from './components/DisplayInput.vue';

  
  
  export default {
      name: 'App',
      components: {
          ButtonIO,
          DisplayInput,
      }, 
  }

</script>
```

Comment: in your case an event bus is perfect to handle the problem

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, the "EventBus" pattern is my favorite.

Basically you create a separate Vue instance that your application will use to subscribe to events.

In your files directory

```js
// eventBus.js
const eventBus = new Vue()
export default eventBus
```

In any component/page where you want to react to an event (subscribe):

```js
// ChildComponent.vue
import eventBus from './eventBus'

export default {
  mounted() {
    // adding eventBus listener
    eventBus.$on('custom-event', () => {
      console.log('Custom event triggered!')
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    // removing eventBus listener
    eventBus.$off('custom-event')
  }
}
```

In the component that trigger the event

```js
// ParentComponent.vue
import eventBus from './eventBus'

export default {
  methods: {
    sendCustomEvent() {
      // sending the event
      eventBus.$emit('custom-event')
    }
  }
}
```

You can even pass arguments you expect to receive in the event handler

```js
eventBus.$emit('update-theme-color', '#000')
```

```js
eventBus.$on('update-theme-color', (color) => {
  console.log(`Updating theme color ${color}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

The events are sent to the parent component, so you can't send it directly to sibling components the way you tried.

For your app you could define an exposed method in your `DisplayInput` and call it from the App component which in its turn listens for the button clicks. Since the App knows which button is clicked you don't need a separate button component for that:

App.vue:

```
<script setup>
  
  import DisplayInput from './DisplayInput.vue';
  import {ref} from 'vue';

  const rows = '1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 | + - * / | ='.split(' | ').map(row=>row.split(' '));
  
  const input = ref();
  
</script>

<template>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <DisplayInput ref="input"/>
        </div>
          <div v-for="row in rows" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button v-for="button in row" @click="input.handleInput(button)" 
             class="btn btn-secondary m-2" type="button">{{ button }}</button>
          </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

DisplayInput.vue:

```
<script setup>
defineExpose({handleInput});
import {ref} from 'vue';

const value=ref('');

function handleInput(_value){
    value.value += _value;
}
</script>
<template>

<input type="text" :value="value" class="form-control" @trigger-emit='handleEmit'>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of emitting events is pretty well documented by vue: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#declaring-emitted-events

With emits, you can trigger a function inside a parent component from the child component and send data with it. You can't just magically listen to any event from anywhere, the event is propagated by the component where it is declared.

So in your code you cant have your `input` tag listening for a event, that the input can't emit. Only the component you declared the emit on does emit the event on a defined action. So in your case, whenever someone clicks the button inside your `ButtonIO` component, this component triggers the emit to the parent.

In your case, you can listen to the button clicks in your `App.vue` file like the following:

```js
<template>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <DisplayInput />
        </div>
        
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <ButtonIO value="1" @trigger-emit='handleEmit'/>
            <ButtonIO value="2" @trigger-emit='handleEmit'/>
            <ButtonIO value="3" @trigger-emit='handleEmit'/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import ButtonIO from './components/ButtonIO.vue';
  import DisplayInput from './components/DisplayInput.vue';

  
  
  export default {
      name: 'App',
      components: {
          ButtonIO,
          DisplayInput,
      },
      methods: {
          handleEmit(data) {
            console.log("Clicked", data); // prints "Clicked 3" if you clicked on button 3, because that value is emitted and taken by the function
          }
      }
  }

</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: So the emit is written twice, once insidee the component like this: @click="$emit('trigger-emit', value)" then another time outside the component when its written as a tag <ButtonIO @trigger-emit="myHandle"> which in turn is the listener.

Comment: Kinda correct, yes. You can trigger any event inside a component with `$emit('name-of-the-event', optional_data)`. This can be placed anywhere inside your component, so you decide on which interaction this event is fired by your own component. And then you can listen to this event when you use that component. So you have your Component and add the listener to it, just like `@click` on a button that is triggered on clicking the button. So e.g. `<MyComp @name-of-the-event='functionToExecute'>` is executed whenever you emit that event inside the component (can be on multiple places)

Comment: But just read the website carefully, it's all there in all it's detailed beauty https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html